# Discovering memory type

Tags: c#, memory, wmi

I have been googling for awhile now and cannot discover if there is a generic way to see what type of memory (pc2700, pc3200, etc.) is used within a given workstation. Does anyone know how to extract this information?

Comment: How generic? It seems that this would be a very platform (both OS and language) specific issue.

Comment: I would love say a windows class, but I could see if this needed to go down further

Comment: Ummmmm what is a windows class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `WMI`, use [`Win32_PhysicalMemory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394347(VS.85).aspx).

In `Linux`, use `dmidecode -t memory`.

Comment: Guess I was thinking in the wrong space, thanks for your help